# Need to mock a non test method in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, celery, django-celery

I have a test class just like the one below:

```
@mock.patch('myapp.apps.mytask1.views.image_processing.apply_async')
class SortAPITestCase(APITestCase):


    def hit_scan("""some args"""):
        scan_uri = 'some url'
        data = 'some data'
        resp = self.client.post(scan_uri, data=data)
        id = resp.data['id']
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 201)
        return data, id

    def setUp(self):
        super(SortAPITestCase, self).setUp()
        self.scan_data, self.id = self.hit_scan()

    def test_1(self, mock_obj):
        .....

    def test_2(self, mock_obj):
        .....
```

In `myapp.apps.mytask1.views`, there is the Scan API, where there is `post` method which calls a celery task like:

```
def post("""some args"""):
    """ here there is a celery task that gets called"""
    image_processing.apply_async(
        args=[img_data], queue='image', countdown=10
    )
```

*The celery task prints out a message when it is called somewhat like below*

```
@shared_task
def image_processing(img_data):
    if os.isfile(img_file):
        print "File Not Present"
```

So, whenever `img_file` is not present it prints out `File Not Present`. When the test fucntions(with mock) post to the Scan API, this print message is not printed on the console because of mock. But the `hit_scan()` method when posts to Scan API, then this message gets printed as the celery task is not getting mocked. Can I mock the celery task in `hit_scan`??

So, Is there way to prevent the print statement from coming up in the console when I run the test??

By the way, all the test cases pass. There is no problem from that point of view. I just wanted the console to look better with only `....` instead of the print statements from celery task also showing up.

**Edit**: Solved the problem. Here is what I did

```
@mock.patch('myapp.apps.mytask1.views.image_processing.apply_async')
def hit_scan(self, mock_obj, """some args"""):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the method being outside of the test; Python makes no such distinction. However your syntax for mocking is consult wrong: you need to reference the thing you want to mock via a Python module path, not a file path.

```
 @mock.patch('path.something.file.apply_async')
```

Comment: I've edited the question with the actual `mock.patch()`. Whenver `hit_scan()` gets called in a `test_` function, it does not print the statement in the celery task. I've checked that..

Comment: The thing that you mentioned is not the problem. Hope you have seen my edited question.. Thanks